# Where is my mistake in calculating $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty|2f_N(n)-f_N(n+1)-f_N(n-1)|^2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the problem

[image]

We assume $N$ is an even number. I notice that terms corresponding to $n > N+1$ and $n < -(N+1)$ are all $0$. The values at the endpoints $N+1$ and $N$ are $1$ and $9$, respectively, and the same for the negative endpoints. All the inner terms are $16$. There are $N-1$ ''inner'' terms (e.g., from $1$ to $N-1$), hence when we include $0$, we get that the sum equals $16(2N-1) + 1 + 9 + 1 + 9 = 32N + 4$. But, the answer must be $32N+16$ to conform to the rest of the exercise, so I'm thinking I've made a mistake, but where?

**Edit:** (for context)

Here is my reason for why it should be $32N+16$:

Let $Tf(n) = 2f(n) - f(n+1) - f(n-1)$. Let $\| f \| = \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(n) \rvert^2\right)^{1/2}$. We have that $\|f_N\|^2 = 2N+1$. As we might have established, $\|Tf(n)\|^2 = 32N+4$. We know (from the exercise) that $\|T\|_{op} \leq 4$, where $\|T\|_{op}$ is the operator norm of $T$. We are supposed to show that, in fact, $\|T\|_{op} = 4$. That is the purpose of $f_N$ --- to get that $\|Tf_N\| = 4 \|f_N\|$, which doesn't work unless $\|Tf_N\| = \sqrt{32N+16} = 4\sqrt{2N+1} = 4\|f_N\|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a spreadsheet to check the $N=4$ case and $32N+4$ is correct.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. So at least according to my reasoning it is correct. Perhaps my reasoning is wrong then.

Comment: No, your reasoning, at least for this part, is fine.  Maybe your reasoning about why it has to be $32N+16$ is incorrect, or maybe the problem is incorrect.  Because the summand is squared, it doesn't matter whether $N$ is even or odd.

Comment: I'll update the post if this is too long, but here is my reason for why it should be $32N+16$: Let $Tf(n) = 2f(n) - f(n+1) - f(n-1)$. Let $\| f \| = \left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert f(n) \rvert^2\right)^{1/2}$. We have $\|f_N\|^2 = 2N+1$. As we've just agreed on, $\|Tf(n)\|^2 = 32N+4$. We know (from the exercise) that $\|T\|_{op} \leq 4$, where $\|T\|_{op}$ is the operator norm of $T$. We are supposed to show that, in fact, $\|T\|_{op} = 4$. That is the purpose of $f_N$ --- to get that $\|Tf_N\| = 4 \|f_N\|$, which doesn't work unless $\|Tf_N\| = \sqrt{32N+16} = 4\sqrt{2N+1} = 4\|f_N\|$.

Comment: Probably the error between $+16$ and $+4$ disappears as $N$ gets large.  The important thing is the $32N$ part.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The answer should be correct. If it is of interest, I realized, with some help, that it is in fact not necessary to show that $\|Tf_N\| = 4\|f_N\|$ to establish that $\|T\|_{op} = 4$.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same result as you did

It is possible to redefine the function as

$$f(n) = (-1)^{n} \space \space \left | n \right | \le N $$
$$f(n) = 0 \space \space \left | n \right | \gt N$$

The problem simplifies to
$$\left | 2(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n}+(-1)^{n} \right |   ^{2}$$
$$4^{2}$$

Counting integers in the set $[-N , N ]$

Total to  $ 2N + 1$ integers

The sum is
$$32N + 16$$

Comment: Thanks. So if I'm understanding correctly, we can consider your formula up to $N-1$, as it doesn't hold for the endpoints. Hence, $32(N-1) + 16 + 20 = 32N+4$, where $20$ captures the values at $\pm N$ and $\pm(N+1)$.

Comment: Yes , I made the mistake $f(n)=(-1)^{n} \space$ holds good only on [-N , N]